# Can't open website from server by its name

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-server-2008

Now i have problem when access PHP website from server by server name.I got message webpage can't be displayed but when i tried to access this website from any other computer in same local network I can access website by server name.

I mean when i connect from another machine to the server by server name `"servername:81/websitename/def.php";` i can access the website but when i use same url in the server i get "webpage can't be displayed "

Comment: What do you mean by _"access PHP website from server by server name"_ ?

Comment: I mean when i connect from another machine to the server by server name "http://servername:81/websitename/def.php"  i can access the website but when i use same url in the server i get "webpage can't be displayed "